# Network Analysis using R

Tags: r, social-network-analysis

I've the following dataset:

```
**Strenght  Movie1  Movie2** 
  23            2        3 
  80            1        2  
  10            4        3
```

And I want to create a graph with the relationships between movies having the first column as the strenght of the relationship. How can I do this using R?

Many thanks!

Comment: There are several ways how graphs can be represented. Which representation you need depends on what you're planning to do with the graph / what algorithms you want to run on it.

Comment: I'm tryig to build a graph that shows the relationships of the movies having the first column as the strenght of the relationships. Like the graphs created in Gephi. Which algorithm I need to use?

Comment: Algorithm may be the wrong word. If you want a graph that demonstrates distance in a network graph as the values in the first column try the igraph package on CRAN https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/igraph/igraph.pdf

Comment: The other part to this is you need to specify your edges, i.e. where the joins are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this R code:

```
library(igraph)
dfr <- data.frame(idMovie1=c(2,1,4), idMovie2=c(3, 2, 3), strength=c(23,80,10))

igr <- igraph::graph.data.frame(dfr)
plot(x = igr,
     edge.curved=FALSE, edge.width=log(edge_attr(igr)$strength), edge.label=edge_attr(igr)$strength,
     main="Graph of Movie Strengths")
```

Works only for small daasets. visualizations get ugly quickly.

[image: igraph]

Comment: Sorry mu ignorance but is possible to make the dataframe:
dfr <- data.frame(idMovie1=c(2,1,4), idMovie2=c(3, 2, 3), strength=c(23,80,10))

reading directly from my txt file?

Comment: Sure, but that is basic R. Use the `read.csv()` function or one of its variants. You might have to reorder the columns, remove duplicates, impute NAs.... standard stuff.